# Округление чисел в python

Tags: python, округление

Почему в python `int(0.9999999999999999) == 0`, а `int(0.99999999999999999) == 1`?

Comment: Тут дело не в `int` https://ideone.com/Jiw6Fz

Answer (score 0):

Потому что точность вещественных чисел в вашем компьютере ограничена.

```
@>>> f'{0.9999999999999999:.60g}'
'0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875'
@>>> f'{0.99999999999999999:.60g}'
'1'
```

Оба числа невозможно представить точно в виде двоичной дроби (а вещественные числа хранятся в таком виде: `m * 2^e`, `m` и `e` - целые). Питон подыскивает наилучшее приближение. Чем больше девяток тем ближе это приближение к единице. Рано или поздно единица и получается.

P.S. `int` к проблеме не относится. Проблема случается раньше, когда Питон превращает строку `0.99999999999999999` в вещественное число `1`.